# Set Width when populating automatically a ListView from object in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, reflection

I have a entity-Dto, for example:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Datos { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaEmpaquetado { get; set; }
    public Guid? ProjectGuid { get; set; }
    public String ProjectName { get; set; }
    public bool EsAutomatico { get; set; }
    public short Timeout { get; set; }
```

I want populate ListView automatically for show details data of a single entity.

I DON'T want use  **AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)**

In  GridView for example, has **AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill**.

```
var myProperties = GetMyAllProperties(typeof(MyDto));

myProperties.Foreach( prop => {

   var witdh = prop.Value.ToString().Length; // ===> not working find , a char like 'c' which width value has ?
   lvData.Columns.Add(prop.Name, witdh);
}
var firstProp = false;
ListViewItem item1 = null;
myProperties.Foreach( prop => {
       if (!firstProp) item1 = new ListViewItem(prop.Name);
       if (!firstProp) item1.SubItems.Add(prop.Name);
  }
  lvData.Items.Add(item);
```

How can I set Width property for ListView Ítem according Value Property ?

Comment: Why you don't want to use `AutoResizeColumns`? Measuring width otherwise is complicated: create graphics, use proper font in [`MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx), take in account *glyph* (space to show sorting order).

Comment: what exactly are your trying to accomplish?  autosize one LV column to content or what?  Measuring character length has no bearing on the "text extent" which relies on the Font, Font size, character widths etc

Answer (score 0):

According @sinatr and @plutonix, I think now better is avoid [Measuring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx) width using **AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)**. More easy.

```
Configure(lvData);
lvData.Clear();
var myProperties = GetMyAllProperties(typeof(MyDto));

myProperties.Foreach( prop => {
  lvData.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
}
var firstProp = false;
ListViewItem item1 = null;
myProperties.Foreach( prop => {
       if (!firstProp) item1 = new ListViewItem(prop.Name);
       if (!firstProp) item1.SubItems.Add(prop.Name);
  }
  lvData.Items.Add(item);
  lvData.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
```